# Pattern in Python

Tags: python, nested-loops

I want to draw a diamond pattern (using 1's) in the zeros matrix 80x80. The first half is going really well but I get nothing but `0`s in the second half.

```
img = np.zeros((80,80))

def draw_pic(image):
    for i in range(len(image)):
        for j in range(len(image[i])):
            print(int(image[i][j]), end = '')
        print()

def gen_diamond(image):
    ret = np.copy(image)
    for i in range(len(image)):
        for j in range(len(image[i])):
            if (i < len(image)/2 and j >= len(image[i])/2 - (i + 1) and j <= len(image[i])/2 + i):
                ret[i][j] = 1
            if (i > len(image)/2 and j >= len(image[i])/2 - (i + 1)and j <= len(image[i])/2 - i):
                ret[i][j] = 1


    return ret

draw_pic(gen_diamond(img))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is in the range checks in the lower half.  Let's look at the arithmetic for row 42 ...

```
        if (i > len(image)/2 and
            j >= len(image[i])/2 - (i + 1) and
            j <= len(image[i])/2 - i):
```

Substituting the proper values, we have:

```
        if (42 > 40 and
            j >= 40 - (42 + 1) and
            j <= 40 - 42):
```

That last condition cannot happen: you need to subtract the row number from the midpoint and take the absolute value.  Simpler yet, just set your loop values directly to the ranges you need:

```
row_mid = len(image) // 2
col_mid = len(image[0]) // 2

for row in range(row_mid):
    for col in range(col_mid-row, col_mid+row):
        print(row, col)
        ret[row, col] = 1

for tmp in range(row_mid):
    row = len(image) - tmp    # Work from the bottom up
    for col in range(col_mid-tmp, col_mid+tmp):
        ret[row, col] = 1
```

Output for a 10x10 array:

```
0000000000
0000110000
0001111000
0011111100
0111111110
0000000000
0111111110
0011111100
0001111000
0000110000
```

I'll trust you to adjust the boundary conditions.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution. It works well on even by even and odd x odd image grids.

```
img = np.zeros((12,12))


def draw_pic(image):
    for i in range(len(image)):
        for j in range(len(image[i])):
            print(int(image[i][j]), end = '')
        print()

def gen_diamond(image):
    ret = np.copy(image)
    for i in range(len(image)):
        for j in range(len(image[i])):
            if (i < len(image)/2 and j >= len(image[i])/2 - (i + 1) and j <= len(image[i])/2 + i):
                ret[i][j] = 1
            if (i >= len(image)/2 and j >= i-len(image[i])/2 and j <= (3/2*len(image[i])-i)-1):
                ret[i][j] = 1


    return ret

draw_pic(gen_diamond(img))
```

Output looks like this for 12x12

```
000001100000
000011110000
000111111000
001111111100
011111111110
111111111111
111111111111
011111111110
001111111100
000111111000
000011110000
000001100000
```

and this for 11 x 11

```
00000100000
00001110000
00011111000
00111111100
01111111110
11111111111
01111111110
00111111100
00011111000
00001110000
00000100000
```